# How to convert las file to 3d tiles so it can render by Cesium not use cesium ion

Tags: point-clouds, cesiumjs, las

I have las file, point data. I want to know how to convert las file to 3d tiles, so it can render by Cesium.js.

There is a demo, point data render by Cesium, but is use cesium ion. I want to use in 3d tiles. Because upload las file to cesium ion is not allowed.
https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=3D%20Tiles%20Point%20Cloud.html

Answer (score 5):

This is a list of open-source point cloud tiler projects.

```
   https://github.com/Oslandia/py3dtiles  
   https://github.com/mattshax/cesium_pnt_generator  
   https://github.com/mfbonfigli/gocesiumtiler  
   https://github.com/tum-gis/cesium-point-cloud-generator
```

I tried to use py3dtile, and its tiling is not perfect but basically works.

Comment: A simple way would be to upload your LAS into Cesium Ion and download tiled data.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/Oslandia/py3dtiles

Answer (score 2):

`entwine` is also a good alternative.

```
https://github.com/connormanning/entwine
https://github.com/connormanning/cesium.entwine.io
```