# Store a pointcloud 3D tileset to a sqlite databse

Tags: sqlite, point-clouds, cesiumjs

I have created a tileset from a LAS point cloud. It contains a main Data folder with many subfolders and a tileset.json descriptor file. The pointcloud data is stored in .pnts files.

I can load and display this data using cesium.js.

My pointcloud has about 53M points and it results in a 970MB folder structure with ~21k files.

For better performance and portability, I would like to store my tileset in a .3dtiles file (which is an sqlite database), just like Cesium Ion stores it.

Are there some tools available to do this conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/CesiumGS/3d-tiles-tools

To generates a sqlite database for a tileset

```
node ./bin/3d-tiles-tools.js tilesetToDatabase ./specs/data/TilesetOfTilesets/ ./output/tileset.3dtiles
```

To serve 3D Tiles from sqliteDB you can use

https://github.com/3DGISKing/CesiumJs3DTileServer

Comment: Thank you, It works like a charm. But I do have a follow up question. Can you maybe recommend me an up to date way to convert a LAS file to a tileset? None of the packages you recommended in this post worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67199138/how-to-convert-las-file-to-3d-tiles-so-it-can-render-by-cesium-not-use-cesium-io